# Is it possible to use a child entity in a key or constraint?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, fluent, ef-fluent-api

I am using code first EF 6.  So as shown below, I have two related entities.  I want it set up in `DocumentVersion` so that the `DocumentId` and the `DocumentVersionNumber` are unique in combination.  So there could be lots of entries for `DocumentId` 1, and lots for `DocumentVersionNumber` 1, but only one entry can have both `DocumentId` 1 *and* `DocumentVersionNumber` 1.  Using the code below, I get an error when creating the migration because of `dv.Document.DocumentId` in the `HasIndex` clause. I know it can be done in the database by making the combination unique or even having a complex primary key.  I could add a `DocumentId` to the `DocumentVersion` object, but I this is my first code first project and am trying to learn from it.  Is it possible to achieve what I am wanting ***without*** adding the `DocumentId` solely for that purpose?

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        AllVersions = new HashSet < DocumentVersion >();
        History     = new HashSet < DocumentHistory >();
    }

    [ DatabaseGenerated ( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ) ]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CheckoutStatus Status { get; set; } = CheckoutStatus.Locked;
    public ICollection < DocumentVersion > AllVersions { get; set; }
    public ICollection < DocumentHistory > History { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentVersion
{
    public DocumentVersion() => History     = new HashSet < DocumentVersionHistory >();

    public DocumentVersion ( byte [ ] content )
    {
        History = new HashSet < DocumentVersionHistory >();
        Content = content;
    }

    public int DocumentVersionId { get; set; }
    public int DocumentVersionNumber {get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public PublishingStatus Status { get; set; }
    public byte [ ] Content { get; set; }
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public ICollection < DocumentVersionHistory > History { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Entity < Document >().HasKey ( d => new { d.DocumentId } );
    modelBuilder.Entity < DocumentVersion >().HasKey ( dv => dv.DocumentVersionId ).HasIndex ( dv => new { dv.Document.DocumentId, dv.DocumentVersionNumber } );
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, you have to make `DocumentId` a property of `DocumentVersion`. That, and `DocumentVersionNumber` could be a composite primary key and `DocumentVersionId` wouldn't be required.

Comment: No, you can't do that in EF6. You can do it in EF Core, but it has other pitfalls.

Comment: Thank you.  If you could add that as an answer, I will mark it as correct.